# Why use Django REST Framework instead of returning normal HttpResponse in views?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Python and I've seen a lot of tutorials which jump into the Django REST Framework when discussing how to create REST APIs without explaining why they need this library. I don't see the purpose of using the Django Rest Framework when I can just define API endpoints in views and return a simple HttpResponse to send data to a client.

What does the Django Rest Framework accomplish that I can't do simply using HttpResponse? Why is it worth learning?

I was going to use the library as it was included in the video, but it seemed more complex than I needed and I decided to try creating an API without Django REST Framework

```
def getStats(request):
    print('--------STARTING Stats----------')
    
    # Take some GET variable
    version = request.GET.get('version')
    
    # Get some data
    with open('static/data.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        
    # Filter the data
    if version is not None:
        data = list(filter(lambda x: x['version'] == version, data))
        print("FILTERED DATA", len(data))
    
    # Perform some operations on the data
    data = calculateStats(data)
    
    # Return an HTTP response
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data))
```

This code seemed to work as needed and I get the feeling that I could make this view more robust if needed based on the demands of my application.

Comment: I'm in the same opinion of you. From seeing that package on stackoverflow a lot, it looks like it's easier to make basic endpoints that returns a model's fields. But it looks like it's generally made around the models, so if you are doing a lot of custom stuff it might not be the best thing to use.
**Side Note:** You should probably add a *content_type* to that HttpsResponse: `return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')`

Comment: Thank you @Nealium! This is a simple explanation and I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The DRF is a complete toolkit for building RESTful APIs in Django, including authentication, serialization, etc. You can do without it but, in the end of the day, the DRF will save you a lot of time.

It fits well with the Django architecture and it's also quite extensible, so you won't be locked-in to some obscure extension, as it happens sometimes.

Perhaps this [old reddit post from Tom Christie](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/3h9oj8/comment/cu5pzu9/) (DRF's creator) can shed some more light:

> Django REST framework isn't required, but it helps you get a lot of
> things right that will be time consuming and error prone if you're
> working from core Django.

Comment: Thanks for giving me context, I really appreciate it! Is it also true that many companies use DRF, thus making it somewhat standard in Python API design?

Comment: Yes, it is widely used in the industry. There are multiple other options, but the combination Django+DRF is a very common stack when building RESTful APIs in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is very simple. When you have more complex logic with orm, permissions, serialization, and others. You will see the benefits of django restframework. You can build a crud very fast using viewsets that guarantee permissions, filters, with the REST API structure using POST, GET, PATCH, PUT, DELETE. You can list, create, update and delete. I recommend that you do the restframework tutorial https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/ and it will become clear to you if is the right choice or not.

You can also use it for your example like this:

```
    from rest_framework import status
    from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
    from rest_framework.response import Response

    @api_view(['GET'])
    def getStats(request):
        print('--------STARTING Stats----------')
    
        # Take some GET variable
        version = request.GET.get('version')
    
        # Get some data
        with open('static/data.json') as f:
            data = json.load(f)
    
        # Filter the data
        if version is not None:
            data = list(filter(lambda x: x['version'] == version, data))
            print("FILTERED DATA", len(data))
    
        # Perform some operations on the data
        data = calculateStats(data)
    
        # Return an HTTP response
        return Response(json.dumps(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: I really do not regret making this post, thanks so much for your thoughts! Those added portions for your example illustrate how lightweight it can be for simple usage

Answer (score 0):

```
Django REST framework offers a bunch of useful features over raw Django:

Serializers that convert between representations (dictionaries, JSON, etc.) and model instances.
Generic class-based views that let you build CRUD APIs with minimal code.
A flexible request parsing system that handles complex request datatypes, like JSON and multipart file uploads.
Customizable request authentication and permissions.
Throttling to control rate limiting.
Filtering and ordering of queryset results.
Response pagination.
API documentation with schema generation.
Content negotiation to support multiple response types (JSON, XML, etc.)
And much more!

In short, Django REST framework handles a lot of the boilerplate and complexity of building an API, allowing you to focus on your application's logic.
```